# How to Install a Suit/Advance UI setup.exe silently in InstallShield

Tags: installshield, silent-installer

I'm trying to install suit setup.exe silently but "The setup command line is invalid.The setup cannot proceed" (InstallShield 2019)

I tried commands "Setup.exe /silent", "Setup.exe /r" .iss file is also not creating, "Setup.exe /s /v/qn"
but is it not working

Comment: Setup.exe /? can give help

Comment: I tried it but it's not helping